# Find marginal pdfs and then compute other related values

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, statistical-inference

Probability and Statistical Inference (9th Edition)
Chapter 4.4 Question 2

[image: Problem]

Comment: I would recommend posting an attempt with a question, as you are likely to get down voted w/o one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Part (a) $$f_x(x) = \int_0^1 (x+y)dy = x+{1\over2}$$ Now for the other one:
$$f_y(y) = \int_0^1 (x+y)dx = y+{1\over2}$$From here, it's easy to see that multiplying them does not give us $f(x,y)$
$$f_x(x)*f_y(y)=(x+{1\over2})(y+{1\over2})\ne (x+y)$$
Part (b)

$$\mu X=\int_0^1x(x+{1\over2})dx = \mu Y$$
$$\mu^2X=\int_0^1x^2(x+{1\over2})dx = \mu^2 Y$$
$$\sigma^2X=\mu^2X-(\mu X)^2 = \sigma^2 Y$$